# Text output of a C++ program running on a webserver and UTF-8

Tags: c++, utf-8, webserver

Supposing I have a C++ program that outputs some text in multiple languages for each user input (like the translation of an input text). This program runs on a webserver. However, if it comes to the output of non ASCII symbols (like Chinese characters or Indian scripts or Greek), what appears in the console is rubbish. Is there a way to display the output of the C++ program correctly in the response to the client's request?

Comment: The console needs to be configured for `UTF-8` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must arrange for your web-server's response to explicitly specify the character set in the `Content-Type: header`, such as:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
```

The exact mechanism for doing so depends on the web server you are using, and how your web server handles executing your C++ program.

With most web servers, when they execute an external program, the external program is expected to produce the response consisting of a list of header lines, exactly one blank line, then the content of the response. If so, you just need to make sure to include this header in your program's output, before the blank line and the content.

And then, of course, use proper UTF-8 encoding for your output.